# Cannot resolve method 'getTitle' in 'Inventory' when click event

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit, spigot

In my event for clicking on kit GUI I get this error "Cannot resolve method 'getTitle' in 'Inventory'".

```
 // Event for clicking on kit GUI
    @EventHandler
    public void onInventoryClick(InventoryClickEvent e) {
        Player player = (Player) e.getWhoClicked();
        Inventory inv = e.getInventory();
        if (inv.getTitle().equals("Kit Creator")) {
            e.setCancelled(true);
            if (e.getCurrentItem() == null) {
                return;
            }
            switch (e.getCurrentItem().getType()) {
                case GREEN_WOOL:
                    createKit(player);
                    break;
                case RED_WOOL:
                    deleteKit(player);
                    break;
                case BLUE_WOOL:
                    useKit(player);
                    break;
                default:
                    addItem(player, e.getCurrentItem());
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am very appreciative of anyone willing to help me.

I found information regarding .getView(), but I couldn't figure out how to use it in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the title, you should use `e.getView().getTitle()`. The view is just the inventory opened.

I suggest you to use InventoryHolder to check for your inventory.

Firstly, you should create a class that implement Inventory Holder like that:

```java
public class MyHolder implements InventoryHolder {
    
    @Override
    public Inventory getInventory() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

When creating the inventory, instead of putting "null" or the player as first argument (the holder, like `new MyHolder()`).

Now, you can do `e.getInventory().getHolder()` then check if the holder is not null and if `instanceof MyHolder`.

Finally, You can put data into your holder as you will retrieve the exact same object used to create the inventory.